# Jquery Replace with return value of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, replace

OK I am just starting out with jQuery.

I have a page with a table of date-values. Each is wrapped in a tag which I can find with 
 $('mytag'). 
`<mytag>2009-10-31</mytag>`

How, using Jquery, would I

1. take each of the source values and
2. pass it to a Javascript function
3. then replace that source value within the table with the result of the function calculation.

So  `<mytag>2009-10-31</mytag>`would be replaced with `<mytag>Very Late</mytag>`

I have the Javascript function written. My question is the jQuery syntax to pass the individual value.

Comment: Well thought question, welcome to the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you will need an element selector, e.g.

```
$('table')
```

Will select all <table> elements in your html. So,

```
$('mytag')
```

will give you your  elements. You will get a jQuery object (not a DOM object) returned. See http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Then you want to call a function for each of your elements. For this we call the .each function, and pass the function to call for each element:

```
$('mytag').each(function(){
    //function code goes here
});
```

(See http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)

The function in this case is called an **Anonymous function**

Then you want to reference the current object in the iteration, so we use the DOM `this` item and wrap it into a jquery object. To get the value, we use the .text() function (http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text)

```
$('mytag').each(function(){
    $(this).text()
});
```

Note: if it were an input element then you would have used .val()

Passing it to a function is easy:

```
    ...
    MyFunction($(this).text());
    ...
```

The text() function has an overloaded implementation which allows you to set the text if you pass a value:

```
    $(this).text(someval);
```

So, we can factor this into our code

```
    ...
    $(this).text(MyFunction($(this).text()));
    ...
```

Making our final code block:

```
$('mytag').each(function(){
    $(this).text(MyFunction($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm, and your explanation was thorough and clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('mytag').each(function (index,tag) {
    $(tag).text( myFunc($(tag).text()) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("mytag").each(function() {
   $(this).html("Very Late");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('mytag').each(function() {
  $(this).text(someFunction($(this).text()));
});
```

---

But, from the sound of your problem, you might be better served by the [jQuery-timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/).  For your particular case, you'd possibly want to allow dates in the future:

```
jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;
```

...and you'd want to create your own language override.  See the [language override examples](http://gist.github.com/6251).  You could define several "late" and "very late" values.  You can also pass a function to each one to change the value depending on how many days ago a timestamp was.